# Scripting - How to create a game property?

Tags: scripting, game-engine, properties, objects

I have a bunch of objects and need to create some common properties to all of them like this

```
for ob in bpy.data.objects:
    if ob.name.find("someName") >= 0:
        theObject = ob.game
        ...create new property in theObject, and set value
        ...create new property in theObject, and set value
        ...create new property in theObject, and set value
        ...create new property in theObject, and set value
```

The result should show the properties added to every object "someName" (someName.001, someName.002, etc) in the Logic Editor like this

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's the `object.game.properties` collection, but it doesn't seem to have a `new` method. You can use an operator to create the property, though, and then modify the value:

```
for ob in bpy.context.scene.objects:
    if ob.name.find("someName") >= 0:
        # Set active object first so operator works on the right one
        bpy.context.scene.objects.active = ob
        bpy.ops.object.game_property_new(type='STRING', name='foo')
        prop = ob.game.properties['foo']
        prop.value = 'bar'
```

I'm pretty sure the items in the list are kept in the order they are created, so you can also access the most recently-created property with `ob.game.properties[-1]`.

Answer (score 1):

Add the properties to the [active object](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_68_2/bpy.context.html?#bpy.context.object) using:

> `bpy.ops.object.game_property_new(type='FLOAT', name="")`
>
> Create a new property available to the game engine

Then copy to the rest of your selection:

> `bpy.ops.object.game_property_copy(operation='COPY', property='')`
>
> Copy/merge/replace a game property from active object to all selected objects

E.g.

```
import bpy

bpy.ops.object.select_pattern(pattern="Cube*", extend=False)
if bpy.context.selected_objects:
    bpy.ops.object.game_property_new(type="STRING", name="foo")
    bpy.context.object.game.properties[-1].value = "bar"
    # ...
    bpy.ops.object.game_property_copy(operation="COPY")
```

Answer (score 0):

Heres another method:

```
def addPropertyToObj(npType, npName, npVal, objPName, objPVal):
print('started..')
for obj in bpy.data.objects:
    for prop in  obj.game.properties:
        if prop.name== objPName and prop.value== objPVal:
            print("added new gameProperty to object: "+obj.name)
            bpy.context.scene.objects.active = obj
            bpy.ops.object.game_property_new(type=npType, name=npName)
            obj.game.properties[npName].value= npVal
```

will add the gameProperty: "npName" with type "npType" and initial value of "npVal" to ALL
objects in scene with an existing gameProperty called "objPName" with value "objPVal"
example: addPropertyToObj('BOOL', "usingFarModel", False, "structName", "MapleWood")

special thanks to z0r